# Failed review audit because answer looked good to me, but it had been deleted as spam

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I failed a review audit, because the answer looked good to me, even though it was a commercial product - https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6882999.

My reasoning was that it was not a link only answer, because it gave some explanation of what it was linking against.

This was the question:

> Address Split Formula
>
> Any idea on how I can separate an address in Excel. Currently I have about 300 addresses that are in the flowing format:
>
> [...]

This was the answer:

> Another, commercial but better way is to use this Excel AddIn. It
> splits the address fields in seperate columns AND corrects (!!!) the
> data. See the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RYD_I9PwX8

To tell you the truth, I did hesitate whether to recommend deletion, but in the end I decided that it looked like the answer pointed to a tool that solves the problem in the question. True, it was commercial, and in today's world there seldom is a need to use a commercial library, but they still exist. And if a commercial tool is a valid way to solve the problem, then why not add it as an answer?

I'll describe my steps - first, I saw the answer talks about an excel addin that splits the address, disclosing that it is a commercial tool. I quickly looked up the question and saw that indeed asks how to do just that.

I wondered if I should delete it as "link-only answer (and not spam)", but decided that even though it has a link, it explains that this tool solves the problem in the question. I am not certain what the threshold for link-only answer is - should it have had a code sample showing how to use the addin, perhaps?

Also, since there is no spam reason, I didn't consider that at all as a reason to recommend deletion, at most I would have gone to the question and marked it as spam.

So what reasoning should I have applied here?

And should answers suggesting a commercial library that solves the problem be always deleted, without exceptions? I'm asking so that I know in the future.

Comment: Do you want spam?  Because this is how we get spam.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a post to an old, already answered question where a new user provides a glowing recommendation for a commercial product. That alone should make you highly suspicious about this, but the topper is that it links to a YouTube video that's nothing more than an ad for this commercial product.

That seems like pretty clear spam to me, as it did to the four people who flagged this and three other people who passed this audit by voting to delete or flagging it. I deleted it as such, but kept the user around to help me cross-reference against other spam from this outfit.

This isn't saying that all commercial library recommendations should be flagged as spam or deleted, but activity like this is highly suspicious and should be examined carefully.

Comment: OK, thanks, I think I got it. What confused me was that the answer looked useful - at least it claimed to solve the problem. Also I never left the review queue, so other answers were not shown as context, and I never realized this is a new answer to an old question. Anyway, I should have deleted it as link-only answer, since it just points to the video. Thanks.

Comment: @sashoalm - One thing I've noticed is that many spammers are starting to switch to spamming YouTube links, either for their own ad-supported channels or for ads like this for products. Maybe they're trying to work around our tools and techniques for hunting them down based on direct links to their products.

Answer (score 5):

But that link is *not* to a tool. It's to a YouTube video. Even so, just saying "try this tool" is *still* not an answer. We expect it to at least give some minimal effort to describe *how* that tool solves their problem and, in most cases, provide instructions on how to use it in order to solve that problem. (And of course, mentioning affiliation if the person is related to said tool.)

A bookshelf is a valuable tool for storing books, but I wouldn't just give someone an unassembled bookshelf with no instructions on how to put it together and just leave it to them to figure it all out.

Side note: There *was* a spam flag on that post, but there was also a Not An Answer flag and two Very Low Quality flags on it as well.

Comment: It seems audits are not terribly clear which of several possibilities they're testing for, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @NathanTuggy What do you mean? They're testing for "should this be deleted or not?" There are no specific "is this spam?" audits and you should not assume that just because you see a potential spam banner on the review screen that you're only looking for spam in the post.

Comment: Sure, but it seems the only way to figure that out is to get stumped by a weird audit and post about it on Meta. As in my case with an answer marked and commented as NAA but deleted as VLQ. Hence, "confusing".

Comment: @NathanTuggy And had you actually tried to delete it as NAA, which you should have done because it's NAA, you would have passed the audit.  You had to say that the post was good, even though its NAA, to fail the audit.

Comment: @Servy I didn't fail that audit. I downvoted and passed. (It wasn't NAA, and I recognized that; it was just kind of low-ish quality, but it didn't hit the VLQ alarm either.)

Comment: @NathanTuggy In addition to being spam it was most certainly NAA.  "Go watch this YouTube video" isn't an answer.  There is literally zero information in the actual answer itself that would help anyone answer the question.  If you think that the post "looks okay" then you *should* have failed the audit.

Comment: @Servy: Ah, we are now talking about different posts. This post here? NAA. The audit I saw? Not, in fact, NAA, but two wrong comments to that effect displayed when the audit was passed, which one can imagine is a bit confusing.