# NAA flags should show the key question info to ♦ mods

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, not-an-answer, moderator-tools

After reading [another question about a declined NAA flag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341596/again-a-not-an-answer-flag-has-been-declined-when-the-answer-uses-a-completely#comment433143_341596) I found it could be easily avoidable if the moderator had seen the question. Taken from the answer by @Martijn Pieters♦ :

> But yes, if I had opened the question, it would have been obvious this was just a piece of garbage littering the page.

And also it isn't the best use of time when reviewing lots of flags to have to open the question each time:

> What happened is that when processing yet another few-100 NAA flags, it isn't always an efficient use of moderator time to open each question page.

Therefore I suggest this review to show the question alongside the answer.

---

Following the concerns by @Tensibai and the idea by @Cody Gray it probably would be better if this would be implemented to just show the question title and tags.

Comment: That depends entirely on whether NAA flags are *supposed* to be reviewed in context in the first place.

Comment: @BoltClock The consensus on the linked question seems to be that if the question was viewed the answer would have been taken to be NAA and so deleted. Therefore, I'd say they should be.

Comment: For a majority of the NAA flags handled properly without it, this means rendering even more text on the list, so spending more time between flags. (considering 1 on 100 per the question at minima) this sounds like it would make more harm than good in the handling workflow. Maybe a mod could post an obfuscated overview of the list so we can have a better insight if the design could be reviewed or not.

Comment: Showing the *tags* and/or *title* would have been enough in this case, and probably many others, which would address the concern @tensbai noted about the need for excess text to be displayed.

Comment: @CodyGray Seems like a good suggestion and if implemented probably the way to go

Comment: @Tensibai, We see the title of the post and the first 200 characters of the post. (Have described that a bit more [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339147/flagging-a-code-style-suggestion-as-not-an-answer-wrongfully-declined/339149#339149)).

Comment: @BoltClock [another castle guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/165773) suggests that link only answers should be reviewed in the context of the question: these are considered NAA if the question doesn't ask for links and legitimate otherwise. "There's really only one valid exception to this rule, and that's when the question... is kinda asking for bad answers"

Comment: @Bhargav My concern was more on how it looks like. Does it look like any review queue or does it have another design ? A picture may help finding improvements ideas :)

Comment: @Bhargav I think I've an idea on how it is designed based on this description and a question I asked on meta, but I still think an illustration of it could help ;)

Comment: @gnat: We're not really talking about link-only answers here. We're talking about answers that are on all accounts reasonable attempts to answer most any given question on the site, except in the context of the question they've been posted in, they're answering the *wrong* question entirely.

Comment: @Tensibai It's not a review queue, no.

Comment: Right, so [we give reviewers a hard time when they fail audits because they didn't consider context](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283500/poor-answer-to-poor-question), and [require flaggers to consider the question rather than flagging the answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314398/) [\[2\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284856/failed-review-audit-because-answer-looked-good-to-me-but-it-had-been-deleted-as), but for some reason this doesn't apply to the moderator dashboard?

Comment: @BoltClock sorry but your distinction doesn't make sense in the context of this question because link-only answers get same flags and pass through same review as old-fashioned NAAs that were there prior to "castle" guidance

Comment: @ArtOfCode that's my point (kind of list with a preview on fixed height per post I assume). Extending the post is easy (already loaded, so just CSS/js) but adding linked informations (Q title and tags) add to the overall load (hence why the comments are 2 click ahead). Considering the ratio of 'wrongly' declined flags I feel it doesn't worth it and we (as users) have to be more careful on how we flag more than adding informations to the flag batches.

Comment: @ArtOfCode but I can't really defend this position without an idea of what the flag batch list look like as it's based on assumptions only :)

Comment: @JoshCaswell exactly because mod should be involved in last ressort, for things community can't handle. That makes sense mod dashboard is less contextual because the context is supposed to have been handled before, when the flag has been raised.

Comment: Not the case here, @Tensibai. The exact same NAA flags go to both mods and reviewers. Mods are looking at them because they _haven't_ been dealt with, or because the review was inconclusive.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Not exactly in the same way, and I don't think mod have an idea if the post has been reviewed or not when seen in a batch view, so I really feel it is our burden (flaggers) to choose the right flag, if there's a tiny chance the post could look like an answer of some kind in isolation then use a custom flag instead of NAA. (but again I've no idea what the dashboard looks like)

Comment: @BhargavRao You see the title of the question and the first 200 characters of the *flagged answer**

Comment: I want to downvote this because of the "show the question" bit, but I want to upvote this because of the request to add the tags :) If adding the question is now off the table given Brad's informative answer, perhaps strike that bit out.

Answer (score 26):

We already effectively have this (minus the listing of tags). When we drill down to the "not an answer" flags, this is what we see first:

[image: Moderator dashboard]

This allows us to process obvious non-answers quickly. We only see a limited version of the answer, and the title of the question it's on, but if we can tell from that that something isn't an answer, we can quickly delete these in a rapid-fire action.

For me, that's the first step in a triage of these: delete all the obvious ones right from this page. That's fast, and can take care of many of these.

If we don't have the full text displayed, we can click on the disclosure arrows to display the remainder of the answer and the first few lines of the question. Again, if that's enough to tell that answer isn't an answer, we can delete with a click of a button.

From this list here, I can tell that #2 is a link-only answer to a jsfiddle (delete), and #5 is a complaint about answers and not an answer itself (delete). #1 is almost certainly a follow-on question, but I'll disclose the rest to make sure (and probably delete). #3 is possibly an answer, and #4 is probably not, but disclosing those will probably reveal all that I need to judge them.

That then leaves the few remaining flags that don't make sense to us, even in the context of the entire answer. That's where we have to make a judgment call, and where pretty much all the flags that people complain about will fall. How these are handled will vary from moderator to moderator, and even on a case-by-case basis.

Some are obviously attempts to mark a competing or well-written answer as being wrong, and we can decline those without further review. For others, I'll pull up the question and try to figure out what someone was seeing. The flag has no context, so we often don't see what someone else did.

The arguments you see on Meta mostly arise because we either didn't see what the flagger did, or because we philosophically disagreed with how the flag was being used. These are things that most likely won't be addressed with any kind of UI refinement, and if we had the full question onscreen for each of these items it would significantly slow down the processing of the majority of these flags.

Comment: "This allows us to process obvious non-answers quickly." it doesn't make sense that the "exception handlers" handle something so obvious, I hope they only intervene on exceptional cases.

Comment: @Braiam: The LQP queue, like the CV queue, doesn't have enough reviewers to handle the load; unlike the CV queue, the overflow is small enough that the diamonds can and do handle it, rather than aging out 3/4 of the incoming items the way CV does. (That is, the exceptional case is the overall system load.)

Comment: @Braiam - If there's something in obvious need of deletion, and it only takes a few seconds, I'll delete it and spare anyone else the review effort. Yes, eventually this all could be offloaded to the community, and I'd like to see that, but at present the review queues can't handle the load. If I can remove 30 obvious non-answers in a few minutes, that saves everyone some time. Same deal with completely off-topic questions, spam that I come across myself, etc. If I'm absolutely sure something needs to be deleted, I'll delete it, even if the community could deal with it.

Comment: I try not to hit the down arrow; it screws things up visually.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Ok, lets turn that backwards. Do you believe that moderators should invest time towards? Stuff that the community given unlimited time can handle (the CV queue included) or stuff that the community, even with unlimited time, can't handle? From the purely utilitarian point of view, the answer is the stuff community can't handle.

Comment: @Braiam: The review system should be redesigned until there are no overflowing queues. I don't exactly object to the diamonds handling it until then.

Comment: @NathanTuggy what do you think OR guys have been doing for a while now? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queueing_theory

Comment: I don't have any problem with moderators processing NAA or VLQ flags. I agree with Brad that, since they can do so very quickly and delete the problematic posts immediately, that may be the most effective use of everyone's time, *especially* given how quickly the queues fill up. The only thing I *don't* like is when moderators reject a borderline NAA or VLQ flag with the "not something that needs moderator attention" reason. The flagger didn't explicitly flag it as needing mod attention, and as we've seen on Meta, mods often apply a *much* more stringent interpretation than the community does.

Comment: hmm you can't see comments... that explains some of mine declined flags...

Comment: @PetterFriberg - Even when I do pull up the full question, comments are easy to miss when you're looking for the source of a flag. If a comment is needed to explain what's wrong, I highly recommend putting that information into a custom flag. That makes sure we see it.

Comment: @BradLarson Doesn't a link to a question in the NAA flag mod queue take you right to the flagged answer? Surely that's not hard to find if so, and if not, surely it's a trivial thing to fix?

Comment: "minus the listing of tags"? And yet we discourage specifying information (such as the language being used) in the title when it's also in a tag? Huh.

Comment: What happened to your avatar?

Comment: @Tiny Giant: Nobody knows. Probably a snafu on Gravatar's end. It shows up occasionally depending on which pages you load and what number you roll on your fuzzy dice.

Comment: @Kyle Strand: Strange, isn't it? It's the same reason questions with questionable titles get so much attention on Hot Network Questions.

Comment: @TylerH: Yes, but that entails either navigating away from the mod queue or opening a new tab to avoid doing so, both of which *significantly* disrupt our flag handling flow. The disclosure arrow does however let us view comments right on the mod queue, at the cost of *two* clicks (one on the disclosure arrow and one on "show X comments" regardless of how many there are).

Comment: @BoltClock Ideally clicking the link would just load it inside the page (just use Ajax to load the contents of the question in place of the answer, or show it under a dropdown arrow that you can re-collapse), so no navigation is required. The whole group of queues for users and mods seems haphazardly thrown together though. They could do with a thorough overhaul.

Comment: What about editing your administrator view to show the recent 5 comments posted in a timespan of 1 minute around the naa flag?