# NAA flag declined for completely unrelated answer

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, wrong-answers

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931562/1351167) since it doesn't even reflect anything OP was asking in [his question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289498/running-batch-file-in-background-when-windows-boots-up/10931562).

The question was, in short, about running a batch file silently on Windows startup.

[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10931562/1351167) contained this statement:

> You can just use the start command.
>
> Start google.com
>
> This will open it in your default browser.

You can clearly see that this does not even attempt to answer anything, it's unrelated and I therefore flagged it as "Not an answer", but my flag was declined.

I cannot understand why. Hopefully someone can clear this up.

Comment: I would just downvote and move on. NAA flags are for *obvious* non-answers.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I see where you're coming from. But imho this is obvious, it's talking about `running scripts on startup` and the answer is `start <link>, opens web browser.`

Comment: @JanesAbouChleih It isn't obvious, because it looks like they're trying to answer a question.  The question isn't visible from the moderation menu.  There is thus no context.  So it has to be evaluated on its own merits.. which makes it look like an answer.

Comment: @Daedalus In the LQ queue we can see the questions, when reviewing an answer.

Comment: Hm, reviewed by 2 (including OP of this question), both "Recommend Deletion". Yet still the review is "invalidated"? [Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/16518308), [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/10931562/timeline).

Comment: `But imho this is obvious` it may be to you and me, in this instance. But moderation is a quick process and moderators/reviewers can't be expected to have the domain knowledge in every tag to resolve edge cases.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Then they should have skipped. Domain knowledge isn't always required when reviewing. But when lack of domain knowledge prevents one from judging if the answer actually answers the question, one should use "Skip".

Comment: @S.L.Barth I specifically said the moderation queue, not the LQ queue, because that is what I am aware of concerning that flag: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268438/785241

Comment: @Daedalus Ok, that clarifies it. Thanks! I don't  see that queue in the timeline though.

Comment: @Daedalus OK, then it makes sense and clears it up, thought that mods see questions similar to the "normal" review queues.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Finally found the post; as it turns out, it was on the uber meta and was one of my questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224452/184887

Comment: Also related to this comment discussion, here on MSO: [NAA flags should show the key question info to mods](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/341797)